# Close case layout in Case feed change status

Tags: casefeed

I have case feed enabled in my org and I would like know how can I trigger the Close Case layout whenever I close the case from the 'Change Status' section?

Under the 'Change Status' section I am able to select the Close status but it did not prompt me the close case layout for me to select the closure reason while if I click Close button in detail view it will prompt me to close case layout for closure reason.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of closing the case from the Update Status Action, you could create a new Action on the Case object for "Close Case".  On the Layout for that Action you can include any fields that you want to be completed while closing, and you can make them Required on that Action Layout.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that the special layout will happen when you're using Case Feed. That's only when using the standard case detail view.

You may wish to make a special record type called "Closed Case" and have a case feed page layout that includes the fields you need (such as closure reason) and makes those fields required.